# Spring integration + logging response time for http adapters(or any endpoint)

Tags: spring-integration

As part of non-functional requirements, I have to log the response time for each http-outbound calls in my spring integration flow.

I have a series of http:outbound-gateway's which make REST API calls (request/response in JSON). I have to log different things like request payload, service endpoint name, status (success/failure).

I have tried to use ChannelInterceptorAdapter like:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.Message;
import org.springframework.integration.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.interceptor.ChannelInterceptorAdapter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component(value = "integrationLoggingInterceptor")
public class IntegrationLoggingInterceptor extends ChannelInterceptorAdapter  {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IntegrationLoggingInterceptor.class);

    @Override
    public void postSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel, boolean sent) {
        LOGGER.debug("Post Send - Channel " + channel.getClass());
        LOGGER.debug("Post Send - Headers: " + message.getHeaders() + " Payload: " + message.getPayload() + " Message sent?: " + sent);
    }

    @Override
    public Message<?> postReceive(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
        try {
            LOGGER.debug("Post Receive - Channel " + channel.getClass());
            LOGGER.debug("Post Receive - Headers: " + message.getHeaders() + " Payload: " + message.getPayload());
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Error in post receive : ", ex);
        }
        return message;
    }

}
```

But I am not able to figure out how to get response times for each http:outbound-gateway.

Any pointers/suggestions/hints/advice would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, you should write `Interceptor` but not for `channel` and for `<int-http:outbound-gateway>`. There is a feature [`<request-handler-advice-chain>`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain)

It can be any implementation of AOP `Advice`. For your purpose the `MethodInterceptor` is a good choice. The advice is applied for `AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage`, where the real 'hard' work is done.

Comment: I got it to work with:     

 <http:outbound-gateway id="requestGateway" ...>
  <request-handler-advice-chain>
            <ref bean="integrationInterceptor" />
             <request-handler-advice-chain>
 </http:outbound-gateway>
 
 <bean id="integrationInterceptor" class="com.example.IntegrationInterceptor" />
 
 <aop:config>
  <aop:pointcut id="all"
   expression="execution(* org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(..))" />
  <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="all"
   advice-ref="integrationInterceptor" order="1" />
 </aop:config>