# Spring Integration is there an advice-handler equivalent for http:inbound-gateway?

Tags: spring, logging, spring-integration

Thanks to a previous question answered here on stackoverflow, I was able to set up a mechanism for logging calls to `http:outbound-gateway` using an advice chain added to the gateway.  ( [Spring Integration AOP for Logging outbound Http requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73623988/spring-integration-aop-for-logging-outbound-http-requests) ).  Now I'm looking for something equivalent for `http:inbound-gateway` that would allow me to log inbound HTTP calls.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a wire tap to the gateway's request channel.

Comment: It's convenient to add advice to the ```http:outbound-gateway``` using a ```BeanPostProcessor``` so I was hoping for something similar on ```http:inbound-gateway```.  The type of the component itself is enough to add the advice.  Whereas having to add a ```wiretap``` on a per-component basis, using the ```request-channel```, doesn't give a general solution applicable from a PostProcessor, at least not very easily from what I can see.

Comment: Perhaps a global wiretap, in conjunction with message history, by looking at the type of the latest message history entry.

Comment: You probably just can add a `HandlerInterceptor` to your configuration to catch requests and responses: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-config-interceptors

Comment: Would there be any new ways to add an interceptor or advice to an ```http:inbound-gateway``` with Spring-Integration 6?